# How can I put null values to separate field and others to different to field in MongoDB aggregation?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following document in my collection.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55961a28bffebcb8058b4570"),
"title" : "BackOffice 2",
"cts" : NumberLong(1435900456),
"todo_items" : [
    {
        "id" : "55961a42bffebcb7058b4570",
        "task_desc" : "test 1",
        "completed_by" : "557fccb5bffebcf7048b457c",
        "completed_date" : NumberLong(1436161096)
    },
    {
        "id" : "559639afbffebcc7098b45a6",
        "task_desc" : "test 2",
        "completed_by" : "557fccb5bffebcf7048b457c",
        "completed_date" : NumberLong(1435911809)
    },
    {
        "id" : "559a22f5bffebcb0048b476c",
        "task_desc" : "test 3",
    }
],
"uts" : NumberLong(1436164853)
}
```

I need an aggregation query to perform following, if there is field "completed_by" and "completed_date" and if there is a value which is not null push in to the "completed" array field, otherwise push them into the "incomplete" field.

Following is a sample result I want.

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("55961a28bffebcb8058b4570"),
  "completed" : [
     {
       "id":"557fccb5bffebcf7048b457c",
       "title":"test 1",
       "completed_by" : "557fccb5bffebcf7048b457c",
       "completed_date" : NumberLong(1436161096)
     },
     {
       "id":"557fccb5bffebcf7048b457c",
       "title":"test 1",
       "completed_by" : "557fccb5bffebcf7048b457c",
       "completed_date" : NumberLong(1436161096)
     }
    ],
 "incomplete":[
     {
       "id" : "559a22f5bffebcb0048b476c",
       "title" : "test 3"
     }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Check this similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24500564/4772988

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as your "array" items have "distinct" identifiers ( which they have ) there are a couple of approaches to this;

Firstly, without actually "aggregating accross documents":

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "title": 1,
        "cts": 1,
        "completed": { "$setDifference": [
            { "$map": {
                "input": "$todo_items",
                "as": "i",
                "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                        "$$i.completed_date",
                        "$$i",
                        false
                    ]
                }
            }},
           [false]
        ]},
        "incomplete": { "$setDifference": [
            { "$map": {
                "input": "$todo_items",
                "as": "i",
                "in": {
                    "$cond": [
                        "$$i.completed_date",
                        false,
                        "$$i"
                    ]
                }
            }},
           [false]
        ]}
    }}
])
```

That requires that you at least have MongoDB 2.6 available on the server in order to use the required [**`$map`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) and [**`$setDifference`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/) operators. It's pretty fast considering that all the work is done in a single [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) stage.

The alternative, which you should only use when "aggregating across documents", is available to all versions supporting the aggregation framework post MongoDB 2.2:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$todo_items" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "title": { "$first": "$title" },
        "cts": { "$first": "$cts" },
        "completed": { 
            "$addToSet": {
                "$cond": [
                    "$todo_items.completed_date",
                    "$todo_items",
                    null
                ]
            }
        },
        "incomplete": {
            "$addToSet": {
                "$cond": [
                    "$todo_items.completed_date",
                    null,
                    "$todo_items",
                ]
            }
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$completed" },
    { "$match": { "completed": { "$ne": null } } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "title": { "$first": "$title" },
        "cts": { "$first": "$cts" },
        "completed": { "$push": "$completed" },
        "incomplete": { "$first": "$incomplete" }
    }}
    { "$unwind": "$incomplete" },
    { "$match": { "incomplete": { "$ne": null } } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "title": { "$first": "$title" },
        "cts": { "$first": "$cts" },
        "completed": { "$first": "$completed" },
        "incomplete": { "$push": "$incomplete" }
    }}
])
```

Which isn't entirely all there since you need to cater for conditions where an array may end up empty. But that is not the real lesson here since MongoDB 2.6 is already a couple of years in circulation.

In aggregation, you cannot **really exclude** the "null/false" results, but you can "filter" them.

Also, unless you are actually "aggregating accross documents" as mentioned already, then the second form with [`$unwind`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) to process the arrays comes with a "lot" of overhead. So you really should be altering the array contents in your client code as each document is read.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check the below :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
 {$unwind : "$todo_items"},
 {$group: {_id : "$_id" , completed : {{$cond : 
             {
             if : { $and : [ {"todo_items.completed_by" : {$exists: true, $ne : null }},
                              {"todo_items.completed_date" : {$exists : true, $ne : null}} ] } }, 
            then : {$push : {"old_completed" : "$todo_items"}}, 
            else: {$push : {"old_incompleted" : "$todo_items"}}
             } } } },
 {$project: {_id : "$_id", completed : "$completed.old_completed" ,
             incompleted : "$completed.old_incompleted"}}
 ]);
```

Comment: `$exists` is not a "logical" operator. For a logical operator the aggregation framework uses `$ifNull`. Anyhow, if the field is not present then `null` is counted as a `false` condition to `$cond`.